# Scraping the core-text of webpages in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, phantomjs

Is there a module that can be used to get the core-text of a webpage?
Something the will remove the headers / menus / social links?

Thank you

Comment: Try `requests`. BTW try googling first.

Answer (score 0):

I think that varies from site to site. Since every website has a different structure you could not come up with a standard extractor.
For extracting a particular part of the web page, you can approach as following:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

url = "some_website_you_want_to_crawl"
url_response = urlopen(url)
resp = HtmlResponse(url=url, body=url_response.read())
core_text = resp.xpath('xpath_to_core_text').extract()[0]
```